# iOs: When should I initialize upcoming controllers (UIImagePickerController) from a view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Suppose I have a navigation controller where the next action is to take a picture or select an image from the library.

If I initialize `UIImagePickerController` during `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, (I believe) the response will be a little slower as the controller needs to initialized. Also, if the user cancels and opens again, it would reinstantiate that controller every time.

However, if I create the controller during `viewDidLoad:` of the navigation controller, it takes up memory while the user is on that view. Side questions: Does this, however, slow down the loading time of the navigation?

Or should it be done in an `NSOperation` when the view is loaded?

Overall, what would be the best place to load the ImagePicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd lazy load the controller when it first gets called (in didSelectRowAtIndexPath) so it wouldn't have to be reloaded every time, and not worry about initialization time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in your case you will always need an image picker on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. You can load it on the view and customize (camera, cameraroll, etc.) and present on the row selection. Probably it doesn't matter that much. `UIImagePickerController` presentation is very slow anyway, especially with the camera.

I don't recommend an `NSOperation` for this task.